# Wordpress do not insert line breaks

Tags: wordpress, line, wordpress-theming

I have a wordpress site where I editing some page, but I notice that wordpress editor do not put the line breaks in my pages, and why is that ?

I do not change anything for this start to happen.
Here is how it should look like:

[image]

But this is how is showing :

[image]

I was looking for something to fix this, like put some `<br/>` tags, but it's a lot of content that I'm working so it would be a little annoying doing that, any tip ?

Thanks.

**Update**

The HTML generated by Wordpress:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="tagline sixteen columns">
        <h4 style="padding-bottom: 0;" class="page-title">História da cidade de Sorocaba                        
            <p>conheça mais sobre a nossa cidade</p>
        </h4>
    </div>
     <nav class="main sixteen columns">
        <ul id="menu-main" class="clearfix sf-menu"><li id="menu-item-1846" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://vitorgusmao.com.br/"><span class="title">Home</span></a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1797" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://vitorgusmao.com.br/compromisso/"><span class="title">Compromisso</span></a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1821" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://vitorgusmao.com.br/blog_/"><span class="title">Blog</span></a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1796" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://vitorgusmao.com.br/sobre/"><span class="title">Sobre</span></a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-1798" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://vitorgusmao.com.br/contato/"><span class="title">Contato</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div style="float: left;" class="container clearfix page-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ipsum ante, adipiscing eu pulvinar et, hendrerit eu tellus. Vivamus orci orci, lacinia in mollis eget, rutrum eget purus. Vestibulum luctus lobortis fermentum. Praesent tincidunt velit imperdiet massa tempus in sollicitudin lorem vulputate. Donec nibh urna, scelerisque ut feugiat sit amet, varius a felis. Donec hendrerit condimentum felis sed iaculis. Quisque volutpat, justo ut mattis tincidunt, nulla dolor pharetra nulla, non tincidunt tellus leo dictum nulla. Integer at enim vitae metus ultrices suscipit. Curabitur fringilla tellus id metus tristique ut convallis metus tincidunt. Nullam id eros ut ipsum iaculis tincidunt et in erat.
        Etiam sed iaculis enim. Cras congue bibendum urna nec facilisis. Donec ultrices cursus congue. Suspendisse sed lectus ut nisi malesuada pellentesque ac a lorem. Maecenas eu ipsum arcu. Aliquam ultricies enim ac nulla pulvinar id porta lectus dictum. Fusce semper arcu at nisl blandit accumsan. Vivamus non turpis enim, eu tincidunt odio. Ut sodales molestie interdum. In hendrerit semper dui, eu accumsan odio placerat nec. Mauris ut interdum massa. Pellentesque venenatis, urna ut aliquet convallis, nibh neque faucibus elit, nec aliquet arcu tellus id dolor.
        In mollis erat sed mauris mattis adipiscing. In vitae eros ac augue pulvinar ultricies in et ligula. Nulla vitae nisi nisi, at bibendum justo. Mauris pharetra vulputate sollicitudin. In et nisl mi. Sed eu vehicula massa. Morbi vehicula leo quis velit venenatis luctus. Phasellus rutrum mauris quis nisl fringilla pulvinar. Donec dui ipsum, blandit quis interdum consequat, luctus quis lacus. Nunc ac libero eget velit facilisis tincidunt at ut eros.
        Mauris a dolor et augue interdum sodales. Ut nisl nibh, posuere luctus gravida ac, tristique vitae dolor. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Morbi nibh quam, fermentum id vestibulum id, suscipit quis ipsum. Duis accumsan, dolor in tempor dictum, justo felis pharetra felis, a vehicula orci felis quis orci. Proin auctor dignissim mauris, quis fringilla metus sollicitudin id. Duis aliquam nisl ut tellus ultrices varius.
        Nullam ut dui ut velit vestibulum gravida non nec lectus. Cras id lectus sit amet enim condimentum mattis. Donec eu sagittis dolor. Nam lobortis justo id lorem feugiat a cursus urna scelerisque. Aliquam facilisis ultricies leo non hendrerit. Proin magna diam, mattis vulputate mattis in, gravida vitae elit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;<div class="snap_nopreview sharing robots-nocontent"><ul><li class="sharing_label">Compartilhar isto:</li><li class="share-email share-regular"><a rel="nofollow" class="share-email share-icon" href="http://vitorgusmao.com.br/historia-da-cidade-de-sorocaba/?share=email" title="Click to email this to a friend">Email</a></li><li class="share-facebook share-regular"><a rel="nofollow" class="share-facebook share-icon" href="http://vitorgusmao.com.br/historia-da-cidade-de-sorocaba/?share=facebook" title="Share on Facebook">Facebook</a></li><li class="share-twitter share-regular"><div class="twitter_button"><iframe allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets/tweet_button.html?url=http%3A%2F%2Fvitorgusmao.com.br%2Fhistoria-da-cidade-de-sorocaba%2F&amp;counturl=http%3A%2F%2Fvitorgusmao.com.br%2Fhistoria-da-cidade-de-sorocaba%2F&amp;count=horizontal&amp;text=Hist%C3%B3ria%20da%20cidade%20de%20Sorocaba: " style="width:97px; height:20px;"></iframe></div></li><li class="share-google-plus-1 share-regular"><div class="googleplus1_button"><div class="g-plusone" data-size="medium" data-callback="sharing_plusone" data-href="http://vitorgusmao.com.br/historia-da-cidade-de-sorocaba/"></div></div></li><li class="share-custom"><a href="#" class="sharing-anchor">Share</a></li><li class="share-end"></li></ul><div class="sharing-hidden"><div class="inner" style="display: none;"><ul><li class="share-linkedin"><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js"></script><div class="linkedin_button"><script type="in/share" data-url="http://vitorgusmao.com.br/historia-da-cidade-de-sorocaba/" data-counter="right"></script></div></li><li class="share-digg"><a rel="nofollow" class="share-digg share-icon" href="http://vitorgusmao.com.br/historia-da-cidade-de-sorocaba/?share=digg" title="Click to Digg this post">Digg</a></li><li class="share-end"></li><li class="share-reddit"><a rel="nofollow" class="share-reddit share-icon" href="http://vitorgusmao.com.br/historia-da-cidade-de-sorocaba/?share=reddit" title="Click to share on Reddit">Reddit</a></li><li class="share-stumbleupon"><a rel="nofollow" class="share-stumbleupon share-icon" href="http://vitorgusmao.com.br/historia-da-cidade-de-sorocaba/?share=stumbleupon" title="Click to share on StumbleUpon">StumbleUpon</a></li><li class="share-end"></li><li class="share-end"></li></ul></div></div><div class="sharing-clear"></div></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS code is [here](http://pastebin.com/whFii0dd)

Comment: Are you sure it is the editor that is the problem, it could be the CSS formatting? Is it definitely not inserting paragraph tags/line breaks?

Comment: you're right, I change it to 'Twenty Eleven' and it works the line breaks.
how could I find out in my CSS what is doing this ?

Comment: Can you post a link to the HTML produced by Wordpress (use [pastie](http://pastie.org/) or another paste service to avoid a wall of text)?

Comment: Here it's the HTML code:
http://pastebin.com/6RRn08Mn

Here it's the CSS code:
http://pastebin.com/whFii0dd

Comment: the code is live here http://vitorgusmao.com.br/historia-da-cidade-de-sorocaba/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that you switched themes to twentyeleven and it fixed the issue? In that case there must be a function in your theme which is disabling Wordpress line breaks.

Have a look for this in the theme's functions.php

```
remove_filter ('the_content',  'wpautop');
```

Comment: you're right, in functions.php it have this line, should I change or remove it ?

Comment: Happy days!! Comment it out and your line breaks should all come back.

Comment: but, why this happened do you know why ? removing this line should implicates in another part of the theme ?

Comment: Possibly, is this a site you have taken over or a new one?  Some people just hate the auto formatter, and it can be a right pain if there is a requirement for a lot of formatting in the main content (line breaks <br /> is a classic) but the client wants to use the visual editor. If it's a new site you're doing I'm surprised it's there in the theme (especially if it's a commercial theme).

Comment: yeah it's a commercial theme that I bought in themeforest recently, I remove this line that you mentioned, sould I replace it or just leave it without it ?

Comment: In that case I would email the author and ask him why he's put that in there.  IMO he shouldn't have, it will cause a lot of his users a problem, they will obviously want to use the visual editor the way it was designed to work.  Whatever its there for he should have designed around it another way. It might mention it in the documentation, Themeforest insist they provide quite comprehensive docs for each theme.